# Boolean condition with Thymeleaf and Spring

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'd like to add an error flag in my web page.
How can I to check if a Spring Model attribute is true or false with Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The boolean literals are `true` and `false`.

Using the `th:if` you will end up with a code like:

```
<div th:if="${isError} == true">
```

or if you decide to go with the `th:unless`

```
<div th:unless="${isError} == false">
```

There is also a `#bools` utility class that you can use. Please refer to the user guide: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#booleans

Answer (score 11):

You can access model attributes by using variable expression (`${modelattribute.property}`).

And, you can use [th:if](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#conditional-evaluation) for conditional checking.

It looks like this:

**Controller:**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping("/foo")
  public String foo(Model model) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setBar(true);
    model.addAttribute("foo", foo);
    return "foo";
  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div th:if="${foo.bar}"><p>bar is true.</p></div>
  <div th:unless="${foo.bar}"><p>bar is false.</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo {
  private boolean bar;

  public boolean isBar() {
    return bar;
  }

  public void setBar(boolean bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

}
```

Hope this helps.