# Want to load the content dynamically when user click on some required contents thymeleaf

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am very much new to thymeleaf and i have been working on project that works great in jsp.Now where i have to move to spring boot i am facing some problems. i have this controller i want when user requestmapped /staff and **userClickManager** got the value **true** and i want to change the contents in same file that is index.html

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
private ModelAndView index() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    model.addObject("title", "Home");
    model.addObject("userClickHome", true);
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping("/staff")
private static ModelAndView staff(){

    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("index");
    view.addObject("title", "Manager");
    view.addObject("userClickManagers", true);
    return view;
}
```

here is the proto of my **old jsp code just want them in thymeleaf thanks**.

```
 <c:if test="${userClickHome==true}">
 <!-- load the manager.jsp file  -->
<%@include file="homeContent.jsp" %>>
 </c:if>


   <c:if test="${userClickManagers==true}">
 <!-- load the manager.jsp file  -->
 <%@include file="Manager.jsp" %>
 </c:if>
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538900/boolean-condition-with-thymeleaf-and-spring. Instead of addObject use addAttribute.

Comment: well let me check in thanks

Comment: it doesn't integrate into the same index.html file but instead of the opening _blank page while clicking required contents

Answer (score 0):

What does your thymeleaf html look like? If you read set attribute use th:insert or th:replace in your condition.

Comment: My question is so simple this is my old jsp code   <c:if test="${userClickHome==true}">
     <!-- load the manager.jsp file  -->
    <%@include file="homeContent.jsp" %>>
     </c:if>
       <c:if test="${userClickManagers==true}">
     <!-- load the manager.jsp file  -->
 <%@ include file="Manager.jsp" %>
     </c:if>

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/")
 public ModelAndView home() {
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
  model.addObject("title", "Home");
  model.addObject("userClickHome", true);
  return model;
 }
 @RequestMapping(value = "/staff")
 public ModelAndView getManagerPage() {
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
  model.addObject("title", "Manager");
  model.addObject("userClickManagers", true);
  return model;
 }

Comment: just want them in thymeleaf